# getting error on production related to config.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am trying to push a app on heroku, Its gets pushed but none of my assets gets uploaded on heroku.

Its works all good locally. So I check with `rails s -e --production` and It gives me error in `secrets.yml`

It says

> Missing `secret_token` and `secret_key_base` for '--production' environment, set these values in `config/secrets.yml`

I am not sure what It is. Please help..

Answer (score 0):

I believe that for a heroku app to run in production Rails expects the secret configuration to exist. Remove the line within your .gitignore that prevents secrets.yml from updating within version control and then make sure you use ENV variables for your secret tokens. If you don't have any secret tokens that aren't just tests then you shouldn't have to worry about it, but if you do you can use gems like [figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) to configure your Environment variables that will keep your tokens off VCM.

Edit: If you look within your config directory you should see a secrets.yml that was generated with your app. Within the app you should see your secret_key_base variables within dev, test, and production. Within production though you should have:

```
# Do not keep production secrets in the repository,
# instead read values from the environment.
production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %> <- This being your Environment variable
```

Comment: well, I got it working. It was possibly `asset precompile` and in my `production.rb` I had `asset precompile` as false.  So once I changed it to true It works now for me. Thanks

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working. Last person I knew that had this error it was the issue I was talking about.